# MDLMesh, how to apply transform before parsing data to GPU?

Tags: ios, macos, metal

As the title explained, I want apply matrix transform on mesh data before passing to GPU.

If the Mesh is big, maybe it's better to do the transform on compute kernel.
For small mesh, I prefer to transform it before doing any GPU code.

Comment: Isn't it as simple as multiplying each position vertex with transformation matrix

Comment: I am building BVH on CPU, need transformed vertex. There seems no API to change MDLMesh data easily. @codetiger